# Get the identifier of a specific notification when it is tapped in the notification center or tapped when it first appears

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) method (in Swift 4) to handle when a notification is tapped by the user. However, I would like to know the identifier of the specific notification that was tapped, and I have not been able to find a way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use UNNotificationResponse's  actionIdentifier property. In case you notification has only one action defined, this is fine, if it has more than one action you need to use the category in order to detect the valid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was this:

```
let identifier = response.notification.request.identifier
```

Thanks for the response though!